# How to display URL / email in popup window

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers

I would like to display data from Geoserver in URL format using popup window. I created a popup window that displays the data as string. What would be the best way to display email as a link to outlook and website as url?

[image]

```
    var url = standorte
                .getSource()
                .getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                    evt.coordinate,
                    map.getView().getResolution(),
                    map.getView().getProjection(),
                    {
                        'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                        'propertyName': 'firma,adresse,telefon,email,web'
                    }
                );

    reqwest({
        url: url,
        type: 'json',
    }).then(function (data) {
        var feature = data.features[0];
        var props = feature.properties;
        var info = "<h3>" + props.firma + "</h3><p>" + props.adresse + "</p><a>" + props.telefon + "</a><b>" + props.email + "</b><c>" + props.web + "</c>";
        popup.show(evt.coordinate, info);
    });

}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
var info = "<h3>" + props.firma + "</h3><p>" + props.adresse + 
           "</p><a >" + props.telefon + 
           "</a><a href='mailto:"+props.email+"' >" + props.email + 
           "</a><a href='"+props.web+"' >" + props.web + "</a>";
```

It seems like you are generating HTML here, so you can use the hyperlink tag `<a></a>` to link things (doc [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)). The following snippet will create this: [Link Text](http://LINK.TO.SOMETHING)

```
<a href='LINK.TO.SOMETHING'>Link Text</a>
```

Add `mailto:` if you want to link to a mail-address. The following snippet will create this: [Mail Link Text](http://mailto:MAIL@ADDRESS.COM)

```
<a href='mailto:MAIL@ADDRESS.COM'>Mail Link Text</a>
```

Another note: You previously seemed to use the tags `<a>`, `<b>`, `<c>` to structure your document. I wouldn't use those single letter tags, since a lot of them have meaning in HTML (like the `<a>` in this case). Rather use expressive names, like `<telefon>`, `<email>`, `<homepage>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your additional command! I knew the both snippets I just didn't know how to integrate them into the script. Now it works like it suppose to:)

Answer (score 0):

Change info to be

```
 var info = "<h3>" + props.firma + "</h3><p>" + props.adresse + 
 "</p><a >" + props.telefon + "</a><b>" + props.email + 
 "</b><a href='"+props.web+"' >" + props.web + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display an email is as a clickable 'mailto' link.

Here's the html:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=My Subject">someone@example.com</a>
```

This will be handled by the operating system's default handle for the 'mailto' protocol handler, which is often Outlook.